# How to find range this expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics

I am new to quadratic equation and expression, Hote to find the range of this expression.

The expression is:

$ y = \frac{x^2 -2x +9}{x^2 - 2x -9} $

Where $ x $ is real.

What I've done:

Cross multiplied and got,

$ x^2(y-1) + x(2-2y) - (9y - 9 ) = 0 $

Since x was real,

$ D ≥ 0 $

$ y^2 - 2y + 1 ≥ 0 $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$y=\frac{(x^2-2x-9)+9+9}{x^2-2x-9}=1+\frac{18}{x^2-2x-9}$$
Now we know that
$$x^2-2x-9=(x^2-2x+1) -1 -9 = (x-1)^2-10 \ge -10$$

Thus

$$\frac{1}{x^2-2x-9} \in (-\infty,-0.1] \cup(0, +\infty)$$

Thus

$$y \in (-\infty, -0.8] \cup (1, +\infty)$$

Comment: Can you tell how you arrived at step 1

Comment: @RaviPrakash Sure, will update my answer - updated.

Comment: Very thanks, :)

Comment: @RaviPrakash You're welcome :)

Comment: But how this method clicked in your mind?

Comment: @RaviPrakash Because by observation the two formula have the same coefficients for $x^2$ and $x$ terms - the only difference is the constant term, so it becomes very tempting to make $x$ only occur in the denominator.

Comment: And one more help please, explain the line after "Now we know that"

Comment: @RaviPrakash Sure, I've updated my answer accordingly - let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Last thing, why ≥ instead of =

Comment: @RaviPrakash Because $x^2 \ge 0$. To see that let $x = 2$, then $(x-1)^2 = 1 > 0$. the $=$ is achieved only when $x-1 = 0$.

Comment: So it means that $ (x-1)^2 ≥ 0 $ but as we had -10 on LHS, so we need to add -10 to RHS too? Correct ?

Comment: @RaviPrakash Right, that's correct

Comment: And the second last step, in which you have written the range? How you arrived at that?

Comment: @RaviPrakash If $x \ge -10$, then on the negative side, $1/x <-0.1$, and it reaches $-\infty$ as $x$ approaches $0$; and on the positive side, it approaches $+\infty$ as $x$ approaches $0$, and approaches $0$ as $x$ approaches $+\infty$

Answer (score 1):

Given $y = \dfrac{x^2 -2x +9}{x^2 - 2x -9}$

Solve the equation w.r.t. $x$

$x=\dfrac{y-1\pm\sqrt{10 y^2-2y-8}}{y-1}$

Provided that $y\ne 1$, the discriminant $\Delta=10 y^2-2y-8$ of the previous equation must be $\ge 0$

Solve $10 y^2-2y-8\ge 0 \land y\ne 1$ to get the range of the function

$y\leq -\dfrac{4}{5}\lor y> 1$

$y\leq -\dfrac{4}{5}$ or $y> 1$

In interval notation it is

$(-\infty,\; -\dfrac{4}{5}]\cup (1,+\infty)$

Which is the line $\mathbb{R}$ less $(-\dfrac{4}{5};\;1]$

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you replace ∧ and ∨ by simple language